# sympy Integration stopped for particular polinomial function grow-up

Tags: python, sympy

Noted that in one of the integrals that I put into sympy the tool stopped.
`integrate((sinhx)/(exp(5*x)-1),x)`
I tried to rewrite the sinh-function and I put `exp(x) = y`.
Well, I obtained a product of polinomial function. On the denominator, one factor was:
`y^4+y^3+y^2+y+1`
The tool found the roots(4) but the previous poly can write on this way:
`(y^2+ay+b)(y^2+cy+d)`
The solution of the integral go for this step (factorize the polinomial on the way above) and sympy stopped here.
On various sites I see the final symbolic solution.
Is there a method on sympy to solve this kind of integrals?Thanks.A.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. we can just copy-paste it and test it. E.g. here, `sinhx` can be just guessed.. IMO sympy cannot perform **all** operations human could do, e.g. a clever substitution

Comment: Below the followed steps
the integral can be write like:
a=(exp(-2*x)*(exp(2*x)-1))
b=2*(exp(5*x)-1)
c=a/b
d=(exp(x)*c)
integrate(d,x)
and the solution is very strange:Rootsum and so on.
I think I discovered where is the problem.
Putting y=exp(x) we have (dy/dx)=exp(x)-->dx=exp(-x)dy.
Integral expression is:
((y^2)-1)/((y^2)*((y^5)-1))
Factorizing the denominator it becomes:
((y^2)-1)/((y-1)(y^2)(y^4+y^3+y^2+y+1)
Last factor can be expressed like:
(y^2-(((sqrt(5)-1)/2)y+1)((y^2+(((sqrt(5)-1)/2)y+1).
It seems that the problem on tool is reach the above factorization form